# Want to take unit test in rails of 2.2.2, but failed. Could anyone tell me the reason and help me to get the solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I was following the Agile Web Development with Rails,Third Edition Chapter 14.

I used the command line in windows and input the command of this:
**D:\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\GraduateDesign\depot>ruby  -I test test/unit/
product_test.rb**

**The error message shows below:**

```
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/rails_apps/GraduateDesign/depot/app/controllers/users_co
ntroller.rb:48: warning: don't put space before argument parentheses
D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/acti
ve_support/dependencies.rb:445:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constan
t RUBY_COPYRIGHT (NameError)
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2
.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:77:in `const_missing'
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2
.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:89:in `const_missing'
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rbx-require-rel
ative-0.0.9/lib/require_relative.rb:51
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom
_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom
_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2
.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/linecache-0.45-
x86-mswin32/lib/linecache.rb:66
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom
_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
         ... 16 levels...
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2
.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
        from D:/InstantRails-2.0-win/rails_apps/GraduateDesign/depot/test/test_h
elper.rb:3
        from test/unit/product_test.rb:1:in `require'
        from test/unit/product_test.rb:1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is causing the error but you might what to check it out incase you've ignored it.

The first line of the error has this:

`warning: don't put space before argument parentheses` Line number 48 in users_controller.rb.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the error message is that rails couldn't find the `RUBY_COPYRIGHT` constant. This constant is part of ruby itself since 1.8.7 so I think you are using something older.

Given that, you should really think about

1. Updating your Ruby. The current version is 1.9.3
2. Using a newer Rails. Version 2.2.2 is **seriously** outdated. Th current version in 3.2.2.

If your book/documentation insists in these old versions, you should find a better book, especially when first learning Rails. Things have seriously change since Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.2. The fourth edition of Agile Web Development with Rails covers Rails 3.